# Capturing response on failure in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am novice and working on angular for first time.I am calling one service in angular. When the call is successful it gives me the response like User name and his log in information. When call is fail it gives me error message.The response i get on success i am able to bind that on html side but response i get on failure i am not able to bind that on html can some one guide me how i can bind failure response on html. Thanks in advance
Here is my function,

```
function getInsuredWebAccount(insuredId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var web = $resource(webAccountServiceHostName, {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'Get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Basic c3J1bml0ZTo1OUJFODUwNUIyRjM0OEVGQTI1RTU1RjU4NEVGNUE0',
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            }
        }
    });
    web.get({ insuredId: insuredId }, function onSuccess(response) {
        var webInfo = response;

        webInfo.a = webInfo.username;
        if (moment(response.last_login_date).isValid()) {

            response.last_login_date = moment(response.dateOfBirth).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        } else {
            response.last_login_date = "";
        }
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }, function onFailure(response) {               
        var info = response;

        info.b = info.data.error_message;               

        deferred.reject(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your handling the success/failure promise in this method is how you would handle it within your controller.

Since you are returning a promise it has function on it then, which takes 3 functions... `uccessCallback`, `errorCallback`, `notifyCallback`.

In your controller:

```
var insId = [somevalue];
getInsuredWebAccount(insId)
    .then(function successCallback(x){
              $scope.bindToThisInUi = x;
          },
          function errorCallback(x){
              $scope.errorValue = x;
          },
          function notifyCallback(x){}/* not used here */);
```

You can read more about them here: [AngularJS docs for $q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)